# What is wrong with my math?

Tags: c++, math

Ok, so my instructor assigned us to make a program that used a set of numbers and finds the standard deviation of it. My program finds the Mean just fine. However, there is an issue with my math. What is wrong with it. It is giving me a mean of 59 and a deviation of 8.4. The mean is right however the deviation should be 96.4. Whats wrong with my math.

**EDIT:** My Program now works.
**P.S.** I have changed the following code to my current version of code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
//Used To Round The Decimal Points
cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint);
cout << setprecision(1);

//Declaring
double Numbers[] = {65, 49, 74, 59, 48}; //Work On Making This A User Input----------Deivation = 96.4
double Mean = 0, Items = 0, Sum = 0, Deviation = 0;
int Counter;

//Finds The Mean Of The Set Of Numbers
for (Counter = 0; Counter < sizeof(Numbers) / sizeof(double); Counter++)
{
    for (Counter = 0; Counter < sizeof(Numbers) / sizeof(double); Counter++)
    {
        Sum += Numbers[Counter]; //Adds All Numbers In Array Together
    }
    Items = sizeof(Numbers) / sizeof(double); //Gets The Number Of Items In The Array
    Mean = Sum / Items; //Finds The Mean
}

//Finds The Standard Deviation
for (Counter = 0; Counter < sizeof(Numbers) / sizeof(double); Counter++)
{
    Deviation += pow((Numbers[Counter] - Mean), 2) / Items; //Does Math Things...
}
Deviation = sqrt(Deviation);
cout << "Deviation = " << Deviation << endl; //Print Out The Standard Deviation

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @YuHao It's just so I can keep track of what it's doing

Comment: you want `sqrt(sum of means)` not `sum(sqrt of mean)`

Comment: @MarcB What do you mean? Please explain

Comment: standard dev is `sqrt((x1 - mean)**2 + (x2 - mean)** 2) + etc...)`. you're doing `sqrt((x1-mean)**2) + sqrt(x2-mean)**2)+etc...`. e.g. `sqrt(2) + sqrt(2) != sqrt(2+2)`.

Comment: Consider the value "the square root of the square of x", which is what you're using in each step. How useful is that computation?

Comment: you should not edit your question in such a way that the question is not valid anymore. If I understood correctly, you got the answer and then edited your question to fix the problem in your code. However, if you do this this question and the answers cannot be helpful to others anymore, because now there is nothing wrong with your math anymore and the answers are obsolete. If you really want to post the corrected version, you should consider to put it as an answer instead.

Comment: ps: which is btw good practice and users are even encouraged to do so (give an answer to their own question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] however the deviation should be 96.4

It's the variance that should be 96.4. It is calculated as the average of squared differences from the mean, so you don't need square root at all:

```
for (Counter = 0; Counter < sizeof(Numbers) / sizeof(double); Counter++)
{
    Variance += pow((Numbers[Counter] - Mean), 2) / Items;
}
Deviation = sqrt(Variance);
```

Taking square root of variance yields 9.81835.

Comment: So the deviation is actually 9.81835?

Answer (score 1):

Draw the sqrt out of the loop and apply it after the summing.

Comment: I did this, and now it says the deviation is 9,82

Answer (score 1):

There is a fault in mathematic expression of deviation which should be the square root of variance of the set :

Variance = sum ( pow(set[i] - mean, 2) ) / n

deviation = sqrt(Variance)

By the way I think 9.82 here is more correct than 96.4

Answer (score 0):

The fault is as people have pointed out that standard deviations cannot be added directly. A better way to calculate the standard deviation is to take the root mean square (of element subtracted from its mean).